# Por que é muito utilizado Varchar(255)?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Por que em vários bancos de dados, dizem para definir o tamanho como `varchar(255)`?

Por exemplo, em um campo `email` por que colocar `varchar(255)`? Não seria melhor (em questão de armazenamento e velocidade de processamento) colocar `varchar(80)` ou talvez `varchar(100)`? Além disso são poucas pessoas que tem mais de 80 caracteres no e-mail.

No meu caso eu estava olhando na internet, procurando sobre `utf8mb4` e vi que em alguns campos já é dito para colocar `varchar(255)`, independente do contexto.

Comment: Você não queria referência?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

O `VARCHAR` por definição tem tamanho variável, pode-se colocar o tamanho que desejar ali, pelo menos dentro do padrão ANSI. Esse 255 é apenas uma informação de como ele deve ser mostrado em uma seleção, não quer dizer que ela ocupará esse espaço em disco. **Não há desperdício**.

Você pode definir o que quiser, não muda algo significativamente. 255 é um número que comporta a maioria das informações. No passado este era o tamanho máximo de um `VARCHAR`, então podia mostrar tudo.

Alguns bancos de dados usam isto como *constraint* e não deixam passar deste valor, ou seja ele é apenas um máximo possível.

Especificamente sobre o e-mail se quiser ter espaço suficiente para qualquer e-mail que pode ser de tamanho até 254 de acordo com a RFC. Não pode modelar o banco para tratar as inserções de 99,999%, ele tem que ser adequado para 100% dos cadastros.

É o oposto do que em tese deve acontecer com o `CHAR` que tem tamanho fixo. Em tese se um `CHAR` tiver 255 de tamanho é isso que ele vai ocupar mesmo que o valor só tenha um caractere. Digo em tese, porque tem SGDBs que podem armazenar até um `CHAR` com tamanho variável, ainda que preserve a semântica do `CHAR`. Se a linha tem alguma coluna de tamanho variável não tem porque manter uma de tamanho fixo, não há ganho nisso.

Isso pode ser confirmado em [resposta no SO de um dos maiores especialistas em banco de dados](https://stackoverflow.com/a/262476/221800). A [Wikipedia fala nisso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varchar). E ainda tem a documentação dos tipos nos bancos de dados:

- [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SCN73/ch6.htm#varchar2)
- [SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15)
- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings)
- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)
- [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Está escrito na resposta que não.

Comment: Muito obrigado, só queria uma referência

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi na referência no caso do MySQL quando você fixa o tamanho do VARCHAR em 255 sem necessidade causa consumo maior de memória nos _joins_.

Comment: @Piovezan no `JOIN` é possível mesmo

Answer (score 13):

O `VARCHAR` por definição tem tamanho variável, mas não se pode colocar o tamanho que desejar ali, como respondido acima. Esse 255 é o tamanho máximo permitido para a coluna, que no caso do [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm#i287903), o máximo possível é 4000.

De fato, **ele só utiliza o que for necessário**. Então, por exemplo, no caso de uma string de 10 caracteres (em Charset de 1 byte), somente serão armazenados os 10 caracteres.

Answer (score 6):

O Varchar(255) é muito utilizado pois é o valor padrão e muitos desenvolvedores mantém esse valor sem parar pra pensar se realmente são necessários 255 caracteres para armazenar aquela informação.

Não vejo como problema do banco de dados e sim da falta de atenção aos detalhes de quem configurou a tabela pela primeira vez.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que antigamente em vários bancos de dados, o tamanho máximo era 250, por isso acabou "padronizando" esse tamanho comum.

Answer (score -1):

De fato, o tamanho máximo do varchar era 255. Como podemos notar, 255 seria exatamente o tamanho de 1Byte, ou 8 bits, que era o tamanho máximo do endereçamento. O número 255 em binário é 11111111, ou seja, todos os bites "setados" em "UP". Hoje em dia, nos SGBDs mais modernos, já é possível aumentar esse armazenamento.

Comment: "o tamanho máximo do varchar era 255" => pode compartilhar a fonte? A pergunta é sobe MySQL se acreditarmos nas tags, porém você diz depois "nos SGBDs mais modernos", indicando que a frase que eu destaquei era uma verdade em muitos SGBDs