# Tamanho do campo ocupa valor total definido?

Tags: mysql, varchar

Se o tamanho máximo de um campo do tipo `VARCHAR` é 65535 `(ocupa 65KB)`, ele sempre vai ocupar um espaço de `65KB` na database por cada linha mesmo se eu colocar menos texto nele?

EXEMPLO: um campo `VARCHAR(65000)` ocupa 65kb mesmo se estiver preenchido somente com 200 caracteres e não os 65000? Ou o tamanho é dinâmico?

Comment: Varchar não, veja a resposta [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190804/66203)

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Se o tamanho máximo de um campo do tipo `VARCHAR` é 65535 (ocupa 65KB), ele sempre vai ocupar um espaço de 65KB na database por cada linha mesmo se eu colocar menos texto nele?

Não, ele ocupará essencialmente só o espaço ocupado pelo texto. É um pouco mais complicado que isso, mas é quase só isto, só não ache que se o texto tiver 10 caracteres ocupará 10 bytes. Depende do *encoding* usado, dos caracteres usados efetivamente, tem as informações de controle. Sem falar que pode ter algum outro custo por causa de truques que o banco de dados pode usar para otimizações. Ocupará mais que 10 bytes, mas não muito mais, quem sabe uns 30 no máximo. Mas se o texto tiver 1000 caracteres dependendo do caso ocupará 1012, por exemplo.

Pode usar sem medo. só o `CHAR` é que ocupa o espaço, usando ou não.

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78812/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Sim o tamanho é dinâmico. *`VARCHAR`* só considera o espaço usado pela coluna e não o armazenamento total da coluna. Isso não quer dizer que você deve adicionar valores altos em um campo, ou seja, é importante saber que você deve limitar o tamanho de uma coluna de comprimento variável(coluna que você pode definir valor).

Mesmo que a coluna seja variável e o espaço de armazenamento utilizado seja variável o `MySQL` alocará memória em blocos fixos para armazenar valores. Por exemplo `Varchar(200)` usará mais memória que `Varchar(5)`, lembrando que isto não é um problema de espaço de armazenamento.

Valor em bytes usado por carácter:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]