# Qual a importância de se especificar o tamanho de um campo no laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Gostaria de saber se realmente é, e porque é importante pré especificar o tamanho de algum campo string/text/... nas migrations no laravel. 
Pelo que eu imagino, talvez essas especificações economizem espaço dedicado à cada campo, mas :
- será que economiza de maneira realmente significativa ?
- será que o campo no MySql já não é adaptável ao tamanho necessário com algum tipo de limite pré definido de acordo com a tipagem do campo ?

Comment: Relacionada: [Por que é muito utilizado Varchar(255)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190799/5878)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em geral, para um campo `VARCHAR`, a quantidade de dados armazenados em cada campo determina sua pegada no disco em vez do tamanho máximo (ao contrário de um campo `CHAR` que sempre tem a mesma pegada).

Existe um limite superior no total de dados armazenados em todos os campos de um índice de 900 `bytes` ( limite de tamanho de índice de 900 `bytes` no comprimento do caractere ).

Quanto maior você fizer o campo, mais provável as pessoas tentarão usar para outros fins que não o que você pretendia, então é uma boa prática tentar escolher o tamanho certo , em vez disso do que assumir que, se você for o mais grande possível, ele vai economizar você ter que revisitar o design.

[Fonte](http://php.docow.com/o-limite-de-tamanho-do-varchar-e-importante.html)

Comment: O que é "pegada"?

Comment: Quantidade em disco